# How can i have individual order IDs for each customer ID?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

imagine a database setup, where x customers can make y orders.
normally all customers would share one set of auto incremented order IDs.

- the first order of customer A has order id #1
- first order of customer B has order id #2.

i'd like to have individual sets of order IDs for each customer. it is important, that customers cannot see based on the id how many other customers have made orders.

- first order of customer A has order id #1
- second order of customer A has order id #2
- first order of customer B has order id #1

right now, the only way i can see would be to manually select the max value for the customer's order number, add +1 and then insert it manually.

```
select max(customer_order_id) from orders where customer_id = X
```

how can i create this approach in a sense of data integrity and normalization? like having some kind of auto increment for the individual order ids of the customer?

```
create table customers
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(255)
);

create table orders
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  customer_id int
  customer_order_id int 
  foo varchar
  bar varchar
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the order number the customer number followed by a sequence number. So if I'm customer 103985, my first order is 103985-0001, my second order is 103985-0002. Normalize the data -- in an order, store the customer number and the sequence number separately. Combine them for display.

Comment: yup, thanks a lot for the reply. i have a question remaining though: how do i properly increment the separate sequence for each customer without selecting max() and adding +1 in php and then inserting it?

Comment: You can track "last order sequence" in the customer record, but I think it's a better idea to select max and add one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a basic relational structure or simply a slug field to select on.

So your orders table could have an auto increment id that is transparent to the customer. Depending on how you plan on serving your data, you could easily use a slug system that combines the userdata to find the correct record.

So for example, a request that was url based - somesite.com/orders/{user_id}/1 would select where user id is the logged in user and order slug is 1. {user_id} could be present or omitted depending on how you choose to authorize viewing the page. So admins can view by get vars and non admins have to validate against this var... but that may be beside the point.

Alternatively, you can use a varchar to handle order id and compose a completely undecipherable string. Depending on the scale of your site this may not be a problem.

Is your only concern is that user B has an order id of 100, you do not want them to know there were 99 other orders before? If so, any of the answers here would work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. i simply want each customers to have a clean, separate sequence of order numbers 1,2,3....100. i simply don't get how to  properly increment the separate sequence for each customer without selecting max() and adding +1 in php and then inserting it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several advantages of using InnoDB over MyISAM but if you are using the MyISAM engine, you can have an auto generated compound Primary Key.

From dev.mysql.com: [example-auto-increment.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For **MyISAM and BDB tables** you can specify **`AUTO_INCREMENT`** on a **secondary column** in a **multiple-column index**. In this case, the generated value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
  customer_id int,
  customer_order_id int auto_increment,  
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, customer_order_id)
);
```

If you want the same functionality with InnoDB, you'll have to use triggers.